# How to transfer not-so-small string offline using react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, offline, data-transfer

I am designing an app to transfer offline information using React Native.
I tried some QRCode libs but I realized that it becomes too slow or even does not work when I have a string bigger than 700characteres. Two scans would be very bad for user experience.
What are some alternatives?
I heard about colorful QRCodes, reading two QRCodes at once, creating a movie of QRCodes. Anyway, I could not find a good lib implementation of any of this. Although it would be nice to use QRCode standards it is not strictly necessary since my app will generate and read the information.
Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to speculate without seeing a concrete example, but I guess you can save the actual payload in a database and generate a QR Code just for its ID, e.g. an url like `http://your-site/payload-id`, which will reveal the actual payload to whoever scans the code.

Comment: It is a solution in many cases, but I need an offline transfer of information. I cannot suppose any part will be online.

Comment: Hello, did you try to compress your string to save space ?

Comment: The issue is that I am dealing with a not-so-long string (700 chars) and I want to stay in the alphanumeric set (not binary). I could not compression that helps in this scenario.